Correct way to run commands triggered by events
I have a couple of bash scripts I'm using to run a command when an external monitor is connected/disconnected or the AC adapter is connected/disconnected, connect_power.sh and connect_screen.sh:
connect_power.sh:
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    if (acpi -a) | grep -q 'on-line'; then 
        powerprofilesctl set performance
    else
        powerprofilesctl set power-saver
    fi
done

connect_screen.sh:
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    con_monitors=$(xrandr | grep -c ' connected ')

    if [[ $con_monitors -gt 1 ]]; then
        gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor
    else
        gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.2
    fi
done

These seem to do the job but running an infinite loop doesn't seem to me to be the most efficient/correct approach for this - is there a better way? I've been pointed towards udev but reading the guidance on the Arch Wiki udev seems intimidating

Lots of solutions in How can I detect when a monitor is plugged in or unplugged?, especially the one about using srandrd.

As much as possible, avoid solutions that involve repeated polling. But if polling is the only solution, make sure you insert a "sleep" at every iteration at least. Avoid calling external binaries if possible as well. If you can write this in another language especially C, write it.

Well, the "Correct way to run commands triggered by events" is to use the event system provided by your distribution. udev for example. I think it's more intimidating to write robust and correct polling scripts yourself.
